# Do we need to use mysql_close() in Zend framework 2?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I am using Zend framework 2 in my application. Recently, my website got down. The server contact person told us MySQL reported most of the connections were timing out. The reason he gives us is that the MySQL connections are not calling `mysql_close()` function before exiting.

Do we need to use `mysql_close()` in applications?

Comment: You shouldnt' be using `mysql_*` functions at all since they are deprecated, and with ZF2 better switch to `PDO`.

Comment: I am using PDO. do we need to used mysql_close() with PDO.

Comment: The Database driver of ZF2  for MySQL is per default MySQLI in php ext/mysqli extension. I don't know why you have to use mysql, those features are deprecated. If you are already using PDO, this should be ok

Comment: I am using Pdo driver. is it automatically close mysql connection after fetching records?.

Comment: PHP will automatically close the connection when the script finishes, unless you are using persistent connections (unlikely). This isn't something you usually need to worry about unless you have long running background tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments of your question, using `mysql_close` is unnecessary since you are using PDO.

As @Tim Fountain mentioned in the comment, PHP will automatically close the connection once the script is done running, **unless** if you are using the persistent connection (which is usually causes problems, I learned this in a hard way).

If the connection to database server keeps timing out, there is a problem on the connection between PHP and MySQL database server, not the script.